# Fennec addon handle scrolling and get scroll position

Tags: scroll, firefox-addon, fennec

I added callback function that is calling when page is scrolling

```
function scroll (event) {
    this.pageXOffset
}
```

When I try to gen this.pageXOffset always return 0.

How can I get current scroll position or current page rect ...?

Comment: That is horizontal scroll. Are you sure you aren't after vertical scrolling (`.scrollY`/`.pageYOffset`)?

Comment: Thanks for reply. My problem is that all pageYOffset, scrollY and others returns always 0. How can I get some scrolling data.

Answer (score 0):

The event parameter in

```
Function scroll (event)
```

Is [object XrayWrapper [object UIEvent]]

So we can retrieve current window object using next line:

```
let wnd = XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap(event.currentTarget.content);
```

Then we can simply use wnd.pageXOffset
And it returns correct value.